# Avoiding duplicates in the stored procedures in snowflake

Tags: javascript, sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have written a stored procedure to insert values into the table. But when I called the stored procedure twice, the duplicate values are being inserted into the table. How to avoid duplication of values in stored procedure.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_columns(TABLE_NAME VARCHAR)
RETURNS ARRAY
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$
var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({
    sqlText: "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " LIMIT 1;",    
});
stmt.execute();

var cols=[];
for (i = 1; i <= stmt.getColumnCount(); i++) {
  INSERT INTO TABLE1 (Col_Name) VALUES ('+"stmt.getColumnName(i)"+');  //DUPLICATE VALUES
}
return cols
$$;
```

**Edit:**

I'm retrieving the column names of a Col_table say `(Col1, Col2, Col3)` and I want these column names into TABLE1.

I called the procedure `call get_columns(Col_table)` and the column names are inserted into TABLE1.

When I again call the procedure `call get_columns(Col_table)`, TABLE1 will have duplicate values as `(Col1, Col2, Col3, Col1, Col2, Col3)`. I want to avoid duplication either by using merge or update or if any other method.

Comment: Can you give us sample input and end result? What's the goal of the procedure `get_columns`?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa Can you please look at my edit

Comment: Do you know the number of columns in advance ? Is there a valid identifier to check if a record is unique ?

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 I don't know number of columns in advance. There is no valid identifier to check if a record is unique. I want to avoid duplication while inserting.

Comment: @R0bert I answered based on the desire to have the insert happen only once. But your goal is to call this method multiple times on different tables and have only the different column names?

Comment: FWIW, the code above won't run, as you can't just call `INSERT INTO TABLE1` in the middle of JavaScript code

Comment: @FelipeHoffa I forgot to add the code " var sql_command =INSERT INTO TABLE1 (Col_Name) VALUES ('+"stmt.getColumnName(i)"+')"; 
                snowflake.execute({sqlText: sql_command});            
             }"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the edited question and comments:

> 1. "When I again call the procedure [...], TABLE1 will have duplicate values [...]. I want to avoid duplication either by using merge or update or if any other method"

> 2. "The INSERT OVERWRITE is replacing the rows of the table when I called the procedure on two different table columns"

Then, if you don't want to insert repeated values into an existing table, you can do something like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO TABLE1(Col_Name) 
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT 'i' x)
WHERE x NOT IN (SELECT Col_Name FROM TABLE1);
```

Replace that SQL code inside your procedure, and you won't see repeated values. Replace `'i'` for the value you want to insert.

(as a general comment: I'm not sure the procedure in the question is the most effective solution to the overall stated problem, but this will fix the specific problem of having duplicate rows)

Comment: I don't want to overwrite the contents into the table but before appending to the destination table , I want to check if the row with same values exists .. If that row doesn't exist then I want to insert into table else not.

Comment: The `INSERT OVERWRITE` is replacing the rows of the table when I called the procedure on two different table columns

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I wonder if there is any optimized method to solve this because if a table contains some millions of rows then it would take so long to compute

Comment: Wondering: Why would you expect a table with millions of rows for a case like this - are you somehow going to have millions of different table column names?